# How to count child entities with room efficiently?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have those entities in my app:

```
  @Entity(tableName = "parents")
data class Parent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String = "",
    val numberOfChildren: Int = 0
)

@Entity(tableName = "children")
data class Children(
    @PrimaryKey
    val parentName: String = "",
    val name: String = ""
)
```

I want to update `numberOfChildren` to count how many children per parent.

Initially I thought about fetch the children, count and insert to parents and then  again to the database but It seems to me very inefficient with a lots of db calls.

what's the best/efficient way to count number of children(based on parent name) and update `numberOfChildren` field?

Comment: Create a specific method with a SQL query instead, use SQL count, that as fast as you can go.

Comment: Autocrab's answer should work, but why do you need this field in the first place? After all, that information is contained in your database already. You're just opening up yourself to the risk of having inconsistencies in your db. All you'd need is a function in your dao with something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children WHERE parentName = "xyz"

Comment: @LasseMeyer All the data is indeed inside the db already, but if for example I've 200 parents inside recyclerview and I need to represent the number..it'll lead to 200 db count calls || It'll lead to heavy filtering on the list...I thought to "save" those operations with entity field. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think best way is to create trigger, which will automatically update data in Parent table on insert/delete row in Children

example of how create trigger from [sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [IF NOT EXISTS] trigger_name 
   [BEFORE|AFTER|INSTEAD OF] [INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE] 
   ON table_name
   [WHEN condition]
BEGIN
 statements;
END;
```

so you create 2 triggers (one for insert and another for delete) will be something like this

```
create trigger if not exists CHILDREN_COUNT_TRIGGER
  after insert on children
  begin
    update parents set numberOfChildren = (select count(*) from children where parentName = NEW.parentName) where name = NEW.parentName
  end;
```

and same for delete, but change NEW to OLD